# How to recover a database to a different page?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, sqlite-net

I created a database with SQLite-net so:

```
 SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Database.db"), true);
 await conn.CreateTableAsync<Musei>();

          Musei musPref;
          if (muss.NumeroTel != null && muss.Descrizione!=null && muss.indirizzoEmail!= null && muss.Immagine!= null)
            {
                    musPref = new Musei
                    {
                        DidascaliaLista=muss.DidascaliaLista,
                        NomeMuseo = muss.NomeMuseo,
                        Luogopreciso = muss.Luogopreciso,
                        Descrizione = muss.Descrizione,
                        NumeroTel = muss.NumeroTel,
                        IndirizzoEmail = muss.IndirizzoEmail,
                        Immagine= muss.Immagine,
                    };
            }
  await conn.InsertAsync(musPref);
```

In another project I need to recover the database created and insert objects inside a ListView, But I do not know how to proceed ..

```
 try
      {
        StorageFile data = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Database.db");
      }

  catch(Exception)
      {

      }
```

And now??
I would like to retrieve the database created above and use it, inserting objects "Musei" that are in it and display it in a ListView

Comment: Do you mean you want to (1) use the created database to read from (2) create a new database that is a copy of the existing one ? Please [edit] your question to add details on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Added demand precise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read from the database you created earlier, you can do the following:

```
// Get a connection to the database that is in the local folder.
var dbPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Database.db");
var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath, true);

// Get all "Musei" in the database stored in the "Musei" table.
var results = await con.QueryAsync<Musei>("SELECT * FROM Musei");
```

If you only want the `Musei` that match a certain field value, for example: you only want to read those in the specific location "Rome", you can do that like this:

```
var searchLocation = "Rome"; // for example entered by the user in your UI.

// Get only the "Musei" in `searchLocation`.
var results = await con.QueryAsync<Musei>("SELECT * FROM Musei WHERE Luogopreciso ='?'", searchLocation);
```

An alternative, if you are only querying a single table, is to do it like this, using LINQ:

```
var query = con.Table<Musei>();

// or, if looking for `searchLocation`:
var query = con.Table<Musei>().Where(m => m.Luogopreciso == "Rome");
```

you can then get this as a list using:

```
var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

To find out which tables are actually present in your opened database files, you can do this:

```
var nTables = 0;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Tables in the database");
foreach (var mapping in con.TableMappings)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(mapping.TableName);
    nTables++;
}
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} tables in total", nTables);
```

and look at the debug output.

Comment: I have an error in this code: `var con = SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath,true);` SQLiteAsync Connection is a type but is used like a variable

Comment: Oops, forgot 'new'. Added now

Comment: I get this exception (An exception of type 'SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in App1.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: no such table: Musei) in the file SQLite.cs just try to run this code:  `var result = await con.QueryAsync<Musei>("SELECT * FROM Musei"); `

Comment: Ok, I was quessing your table would be called "Musei", but it may be pluralized in English as the "Museis" table in the database. I added an example using the alternative `Table<Musei>` syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately, I keep getting the same exception. In the database the voice remains "Musei" in Italian, I checked with SQLite Expert Personal 3

Comment: Well, that means that the file you opened does not contain such a table. I have added some code that will allow you to find out which tables are in your opened database file.